# URL Rewrite IIS 7 - url redirect not working

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a website running on IIS 7 bound to port 80 with 2 domains (for our purposes - example.com & test.com) pointed at it.

example.com is our canonical name so I would like any client that hits test.com to be redirected to example.com.

I have been trying to use the IIS 7 Rewrite module. However it doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever. How can I trouble shoot this?

Here's the rule I put in my web.config.

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="rule1" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*test.com*" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}example.com{R:2}" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was going about it the wrong way. This is the way to do it:

```
<rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

ref: http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2009/04/08/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks.aspx

Comment: What if you wanted to redirect example.com to www.example.com and catch both https and http traffic with the same rule?  You wouldn't want to redirect to "http://..."  I tried replacing the HTTP_HOST but it didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: @ Dr. Zim but why would you want to do that? Https is for secured connections, like login and other information that should be secured. If it doesn't need to be secured you use Http. 

Why would you want to use both somewhere?

Comment: One thing that got me was that I think the input to rule evaluation can change depending on where in your site heirarchy you create the rule.  So for example if you had your original rule applied nested to one level, you might be able to get it to work if you move it to your root / Default Web Site level.